# How to get value from input html

Tags: php, html

its supposed to get the value from the input to pass it in the url but the $_POST isnt working when i give a value to the $nperson variable it works so i think the problem its the $_POST i tried already with $_GET and didnt work either

part of the code that matters

```
<form method="post" action="tour.php" id="nperson" class="input-group-sm w-25 text-center">

        <input type="number" name="n_person" value="1" min="1" max="6" step="1"/>
      <?php if(isset($_POST['n_person'])) {
            $nperson= $_POST['n_person'];}?>
        <div  class="col-md-12">
                        <a href="booking.php?nperson=<?php echo $nperson; ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"  name="reservation" >Make Reservation</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the code above tour.php or is that a different page?

Comment: yes it is at tour.php

Comment: You are aware that you would have to submit this form first, before you can access any of the selected values – right? So you would only be able to generate this link, _after_ the user has submitted this at least once.

Comment: So you load the page (tour.php), put a value into the input box, submit the form, and when the page reloads there is no value in the `nperson` parameter of the link to booking.php?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: If all you need to achieve here, is to send the user to your booking script, with the selected number of people as parameter … well then make your form use GET in the first place, set `booking.php` as its action, and add a proper submit button … done.